# Concatenating strings from different rows in R

Tags: r, grepl

I have a R data frame which looks like

```
data.1       data.character
a            **str1**,str2,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6
b            str3,str4,str5
c            **str1**,str6
```

I am currently using `grepl` to identify if the column data.character has my search string `"<str>"` and if so I want all the row values in `data.1` to be concatenated into one string with a separator

eg. if I use `grepl(str1,data.character)` it will return two rows of `df$data.1` and I want an output like

`a,c` *( rows which contain str1 in data.character)*

I am currently using two for loops but i know this is not an efficient method. I was wondering if someone could suggest a more elegant and less time consuming method.

Comment: If your data.frame is df then `paste0(df$data.1[grep("str1", df$data.character)] ,collapse=",")` should work.

Comment: When you answer a question, you should post an answer and the OP should accept it as the right answer if it works. This way, people will see that there was a correct answer posted for the problem when they look for something similar.

Comment: @user20650 just pinging you in case iraserd's comment didn't :-).  definitely go ahead and post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft , iraserd - will do, cheers - was being lazy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there - (now my long-winded answer)

```
# Data
df <- read.table(text="data.1       data.character
       a            **str1**,str2,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6
       b            str3,str4,str5
       c            **str1**,str6",header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Match string

```
# In your question you used grepl which produces a logical vector (TRUE if
#string is present)

grepl("str1" , df$data.character)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

# In my comment I used grep which produces an positional index of the vector if
# string is present (this was due to me not reading your grepl properly rather 
# than because of any property)

grep("str1" , df$data.character)
# [1] 1 3
```

Then subset the vector that you want at these positions resulting from grep (or grepl)

```
(s <- df$data.1[grepl("str1" , df$data.character)])
# [1] "a" "c"  first and third elements are selected
```

Paste these together into the required format (collapse argument is used to define the separator between the elements)

```
paste(s,collapse=",")
# [1] "a,c"
```

So more succinctly

```
paste(df$data.1[grep("str1" , df$data.character)],collapse=",")
```